# Mysql subquery with where clause

Tags: mysql, subquery

i need a little bit of help. 
I have three tables and there names are hall, hall_quantified_details and hall_hall_quantified_details, and they looks like this:

Hall

```
hall_id | hall_name
   1        Hall 1
   2        Hall 2
```

hall_quantified_details

```
hall_quantified_details_id | name_quantified
           1                       space
           2                       seats
```

hall_hall_quantified_details

```
hall_hall_quantified_details_id | hall_id | hall_quantified_details_id | value
          1                         1               1                     100m2
          2                         1               2                     500seats
```

And i want to get back with query name of value and value for hall_id 1, i have query, but it gives me back only name of hall_quantified_details_id... Query looks like this:

```
SELECT p.name_quantified
FROM hall_quantified_details p 
WHERE p.hall_quantified_details_id  IN (
      SELECT pns.hall_quantified_details_id
      FROM hall_hall_quantified_details pns 
      WHERE pns.hall_id = 1
 );
```

So i wish to get back for hall_id 1 from hall_hall_quantified_details result that looks like : space 100;   seats 500seats.

Comment: You don't want a subquery, you want a `JOIN` between the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple join:

```
select h2.name_quantified,
    h1.value
from hall_hall_quantified_details h1
join hall_quantified_details h2 on h1.hall_quantified_details_id = h2.hall_quantified_details_id
where h1.hall_id = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i have been really confused about this, thank you @Gurwinder Singh